# Bypass pre-commit hook during `git revert --continue`

Tags: git

I was doing a `git revert` (of a previous revert), which caused some merge conflicts.
After resolving the conflicts my pre-commit hook threw some code sniffer issues.

Since these code sniffer notices are fixed elsewhere I wanted to bypass the pre-commit hook at this point using `git revert --continue --no-verify`, apparently `git revert` doesn't have the `--no-verify` subcommand.

`git revert` does have a `--no-commit` subcommand but this doesn't work in combination with `--continue`.

I ended up renaming the `pre-commit` file, but out of curiosity. Is there any better wat to bypass pre-commit hooks at that point?

Comment: had the same issue too and resolved it like you: I created a file `hooks.sh` that takes one argument: `enable` or `disable`. When feeding `disable`, I take my pre-commit hook and rename it to `pre-commit.disabled`. Once done, I call `./hooks.sh enable` which renames the file back to `pre-commit`

Comment: Yeah, the only option is to delete the hooks directory, do the git revert --continue and then do git reset --hard HEAD.

Comment: You could also just temporarily turn off your git hooks: `git git config core.hooksPath ""` and then after you're done with the `revert --continue`, turn it back on with `git config core.hooksPath hooks/` (assuming your hooks path is `/hooks`). This won't work if you just want to turn off the precommit hook (and want your postcommit hook to still run, for example).

Answer (score 24):

#### Changing the hooks

If you are able to change the **hooks**, you can just [add a toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51665074/10095231) for each
one.  Or just use a script to temporarily rename a given **hook**,
[as commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562125/bypass-pre-commit-hook-during-git-revert-continue#comment52980136_32562125).

Either way will **selectively skip** the problematic **hook** while letting the
other ones run normally.  This ensures that other checks occur (if they exist),
such as a commit message validation with the `commit-msg` **hook**.

#### Committing

If that does not apply, there is an alternative:

Usually, when an operation is stopped by a conflict, after fixing it you can
just run

```sh
git commit
```

instead of

```sh
git $operation --continue
```

This applies to `revert`, `merge`, `cherry-pick` and possibly others (although
in `rebase` it might behave differently, since it is a sequence of operations).

So, as noted, to bypass the **hooks**, you can just add `--no-verify`:

```sh
git commit --no-verify
```

---

**Note**: The feature above seems to be undocumented, but it WorksForMe(tm).

From a diff of `strace git commit` and `strace git revert --continue`, the
former does a lot of other things (515 vs 173 lines, respectively), such as
checking if a rebase is in progress and creating some temporary files in
`$GIT_DIR/objects`.  Example:

```
stat(".git/MERGE_HEAD", 0x7ffefb5d0760) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat(".git/rebase-apply", 0x7ffefb5d0620) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat(".git/rebase-merge", 0x7ffefb5d0620) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat(".git/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD", 0x7ffefb5d0760) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat(".git/BISECT_LOG", 0x7ffefb5d0620) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat(".git/REVERT_HEAD", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/REVERT_HEAD", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".git/REVERT_HEAD", O_RDONLY) = 4
```

But the result appears to be same: They open up the editor with the
git-generated message (e.g.: "This reverts commit [...]") and commit after
exiting.  I have used the alternative form multiple times and never had any
problems at least (by the way, I probably discovered it under the same
scenario).

Answer (score 7):

There is the possibility to check inside of your pre-commit hook, if you are in a certain state. Based on that check you can abort the script. The following commands will return a hash when they are in a state like that, respectively, inside a revert, merge and rebase:

```
git rev-parse -q --verify REVERT_HEAD
git rev-parse -q --verify MERGE_HEAD
git rev-parse -q --verify REBASE_HEAD
```

This is how I use two of them in my pre-commit hook:

```
#!/bin/sh

IN_MERGE=$(git rev-parse -q --verify MERGE_HEAD)
if [ "$IN_MERGE" != "" ]
then
    exit 0;
fi

IN_REBASE=$(git rev-parse -q --verify REBASE_HEAD)
if [ "$IN_REBASE" != "" ]
then
    exit 0;
fi
```