# specify which hook to skip on git commit --no-verify

Tags: githooks, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

If there a way to specify exactly which `git-hook` to skip when using `--no-verify`? Or is there another flag other than `--no-verify` to accomplish this? Perhaps just a flag to only skip `pre-commit`?

I have two hooks that I regularly use, `pre-commit` and `commit-msg`. `pre-commit` runs my linting, flow check, and some unit tests. `commit-msg` appends my branch name to the end of the commit message.

There are times that I would like to `--no-verify` the `pre-commit` but would still like to have `commit-msg` run.

There seem to be a lot of SO posts similar to this, but nothing quite like selective skipping with `--no-verify`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to commit and bypass a single pre-commit hook use

> SKIP=hook_name git commit -m "commit_message"

The SKIP environment variable is a comma separated list of hook ids. This allows you to skip a single hook instead of --no-verifying the entire commit.

> SKIP=flake8,mypy git commit -m "commit_message"

Comment: It might be unclear but this applies to `pre-commit` tool (https://pre-commit.com/) that manages your hook installations. Doesn't apply to `git` itself.

Answer (score 7):

#### Skipping

If you are able to modify the **hooks**, you can add a toggle for each one.

Example of a specific validation toggle from [`pre-commit.sample`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/tree/templates/hooks--pre-commit.sample):

```sh
# If you want to allow non-ASCII filenames set this variable to true.
allownonascii=$(git config --bool hooks.allownonascii)
```

So to enable toggling the entire `pre-commit` **hook**, this could be added to
the beginning of it:

```sh
enabled="$(git config --bool hooks.pre-commit.enabled)"

if test "$enabled" != true
then
    echo 'Warning: Skipping pre-commit hook...'
    exit
fi
```

Usage example:

```sh
git -c hook.pre-commit.enabled=false commit
```

#### Aliasing

**Note**: Both types of aliases [break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342969/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-to-work-with-aliases) **tab completion**.

A [`git alias`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) could simplify this:

```sh
git config --global alias.noprecommit \
  '!git -c hook.pre-commit.enabled=false'
```

With that, you could commit and skip the **hook** with the following invocation:

```sh
git noprecommit commit
```

You could also use a [shell `alias`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/alias.html) (in e.g.: `~/.bashrc`):

```sh
alias gitnoprecommit='git -c hook.pre-commit.enabled=false'
```

Usage example:

```sh
gitnoprecommit commit
```

Comment: E.g. `git -c hooks.pre-commit.enabled=false cherry-pick --continue`.You need to have added the default to git config (as a one-off), like so: `git config hooks.pre-commit.enabled true`