# Is there a way to skip hooks when continuing the merge?

Tags: git

In `git commit`, one can do `git commit --no-verify` or `git commit -n` to skip git hooks. However, I haven't had much success in finding doing the same when resolving conflict in  merge step.

e.g.
`git merge develop`
[I run into some merge-conflict and I resolve in this step]
Then I want to continue the merge and do the following
`git merge --continue`
But, this will run all git-hooks that I want to skip.

I've tried `git merge --continue --no-verify` and obviously that didn't work.
I've looked into other similar answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51681982/1204312) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67924079/1204312) but just want to know if this is truly impossible in git right now.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `git merge --continue`, you can use `git commit` plus any options: `git commit --no-verify` should continue the merge without executing hooks.